# Zend Framework: Require one out of three values

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, require, requiredfieldvalidator

For my school project, I am working on a database management application.
It is my first real Zend Framework application.

Now, right now, I have set 3 values as required, postalcode, email and telephone.
They are required like this(Example):

```
        $mail = $this->createElement('text', 'mail');
    $mail->setLabel('E-mail:')
            ->setAttrib('size', 50)->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(6, 40))->addValidator('EmailAddress', true)
            ->setRequired(true);
        $telephone = $this->createElement('text', 'telephone');
    $telephone->setLabel('Telephone:')
            ->setAttrib('size', 50)->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(10, 10))
            ->setRequired(true);
```

How can I make only one of them required?

I am working with Zend_Form, and also working with Displaygroups.

Is there someone who knows a solution for my program? Maybe use an array?

Thanks in advance,

JorritK

**UPDATE**

@brady.vitrano

Ok, the first part of my code looks like this now:

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Validate_ContactMethodSelected
extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
const INVALID = 'invalid';

protected $_messageTemplates = array(
    self::INVALID => 'Must select at least one contact method'
);

public function isValid($value, $context = array())
{
     // You need to use your element names, consider making these dynamic
    $checkFields = array('telefoon','mobiel','mail');
    // Check if all are empty
    foreach ( $checkFields as $field ) {
        if (isset($context[$field]) && !empty($context[$field])) {
            // Only one value needs to return true..skip the rest
            return true;
        }
    }

    // All were empty, set your own error message
    $this->_error(self::INVALID);
    return false;
}

}

class Application_Form_Nieuwkandidaat extends Zend_Form
{

public function init()
{
     $this->setMethod('post');
    $DB = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();


    $telefoon = $this->createElement('text', 'telefoon');
    $telefoon->setLabel('Telefoon:')
            ->setAttrib('size', 50)->addValidator('StringLength', false,array(10,10));
    $telefoon->addValidator(new Application_Form_Validate_ContactMethodSelected());
    $mobiel = $this->createElement('text', 'mobiel');
    $mobiel->setLabel('Mobiel:')
            ->setAttrib('size', 50)->addValidator('StringLength', false,array(10,10));
    $mobiel->addValidator(new Application_Form_Validate_ContactMethodSelected());
    $mail = $this->createElement('text', 'mail');
    $mail->setLabel('E-mail:')
            ->setAttrib('size', 50)->addValidator('StringLength', false,array(6,40))->addValidator('EmailAddress', true);
    $mail->addValidator(new Application_Form_Validate_ContactMethodSelected());
```

It won't show the message after hitting the submit button. What more should I change? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Which one of those three is actually required? The Postal-code?

Comment: So, your asking how do you allow a person to enter any of the 3 contact methods as long as 1 of them is selected, right?

Comment: Ok, please let me explain. It should become a zend form, where a lot of details have to be filled. Name, Adress, Postal Code.. things like that. And contact details are important. So at least one of the 3 contact values, email, phone and adress should be filled in the form. If one is filled in, it's enough. if none, there should be a message that at least one is required. If all, or if 2 vales are filled in the form, it should be fine as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A good solution to consider is to [write a custom validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html) for the elements.

In your, `isValid` method you will have to check based on `$context` of other values. Something like:

**EDIT**

```
/** /library/Application/Form/Validate/ContactMethodSelected.php **/

class Application_Form_Validate_ContactMethodSelected 
    extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    const INVALID = 'invalid';

    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::INVALID => 'Must select at least one contact method'
    ); 

    public function isValid($value, $context = array())
    {
         // You need to use your element names, consider making these dynamic
        $checkFields = array('phone','email','address');
        // Check if all are empty
        foreach ( $checkFields as $field ) {
            if (isset($context[$field]) && !empty($context[$field])) {
                // Only one value needs to return true..skip the rest
                return true;
            }
        }

        // All were empty, set your own error message
        $this->_error(self::INVALID);
        return false;   
    }

}
```

Now, you have to tell the elements to use that validator. So, make changes in your forms `init()` method.

```
 $mail->addValidator(new Application_Form_Validate_ContactMethodSelected());
 $telephone->addValidator(new Application_Form_Validate_ContactMethodSelected());
```

**Don't forget:** Once you have your own custom validator, you will have to remove the `isRequired()` from each element.

**EDIT2**

You must set the custom validator as the first validator in the chain and break on failure. Also, you have to `setAllowEmpty()` to false.

```
$telefoon = $this->createElement('text', 'telefoon');
$telefoon->setLabel('Telefoon:')
        ->setAttrib('size', 50)->setAllowEmpty(false)
        ->addValidator(new Application_Form_Validate_ContactMethodSelected(),true)
        ->addValidator('StringLength', false,array(10,10));
$mobiel = $this->createElement('text', 'mobiel');
$mobiel->setLabel('Mobiel:')
        ->setAttrib('size', 50)->setAllowEmpty(false)
        ->addValidator(new Application_Form_Validate_ContactMethodSelected(),true)
        ->addValidator('StringLength', false,array(10,10));
$mail = $this->createElement('text', 'mail');
$mail->setLabel('E-mail:')
        ->setAttrib('size', 50)->setAllowEmpty(false)
        ->addValidator(new Application_Form_Validate_ContactMethodSelected(),true)
        ->addValidator('StringLength', false,array(6,40))->addValidator('EmailAddress', true);
```

Next, you will have to update the `isValid` method with the following:

```
public function isValid($value, $context = array())
{
    // You need to use your element names, consider making these dynamic
    $checkFields = array('telefoon','mobiel','mail');
    // Check if all are empty
    foreach ( $checkFields as $field ) {
    if (isset($context[$field]) && !empty($context[$field])) {

        if (!empty($value)) {
            // This is the element with content... validate as true
            return true;
        }
        // we are going to return false and no error
        // to break validation chain on other empty values
        // This is a quick hack, don't have time to invest in this
        return false;
        }
    }

    // All were empty, set your own error message
    $this->_error(self::INVALID);
    return false;
}
```

Now, you will have to add another condition to your code that uses this validator. We have to require that the form does not have any error messages.

```
if ($form->isValid($_POST) || !count($form->getMessages())) {
    /** Valid, now you can process **/
} else {
    /** Not valid **/
}
```

Comment: Please see my question again, I updated it with your code, but I get this error: Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'INVALID'

Comment: Wrong place for the `isValid` method. You need to create a new class. A new validator. I recommend you read about [Creating Customer Validators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html)

Comment: Let me add some more details for you.

Comment: Yes, please, I don't fully understand it yet. Where should I place the public function isValid($value, $context = array())... the code you wrote as answer and what should I use as validator? ->addValidator($validator)

Comment: Ok, I put your code in my project, but it still won't show the message. I've also tried putting: $contactveld = new Application_Form_Validate_ContactMethodSelected(); in the code and adding ->addValidator($contactveld) but then it still won't show unfortunatly

Comment: Your almost there. I will update my post with the changes you need to add

Comment: It works! I did not need this code: if ($form->isValid($_POST) || !count($form->getMessages())) {
    /** Valid, now you can process **/
} else {. I used $this->setMethod('post'); and It workded :D You are amazing! Thank you for your help! How can I buy you a drink? 
    /** Not valid **/
}

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach is the simplest one. You don't have to write any custom validators. You just have to check if one of the required values appears as not empty, after the form validation, because then you will have access to the filtered and validated form values.

```
if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {

    // get filtered and validated form values
    $params = $form->getValues();

    // check if there is a selected contact method
    if (isContactMethodSelected ($params)) {
       // the form is Valid!

    } else {
       // not valid
    }


} else {
    // not valid
}
```

Here is the "isContactMethodSelected" method. You could simply add it in the current controller class.

```
private function isContactMethodSelected ($params) {

        // define array with the contact methods as they appear in the $params as keys
        $checkFields = array('telefoon','mobiel','mail');

        // check if there is at least one contact method selected
        foreach ($checkFields as $field) {
            if (isset($params[$field]) && !empty($params[$field])) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Definitely an option, has the advantage that every developer who subsequently works on the code will quickly see the code.  May be a problem if there is already a lot of code in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest and quickest solution is to override the isValid function for the form itself

```
class Application_Form_Nieuwkandidaat extends Zend_Form
{

    //...

    public function isValid($data)
    {
        $valid = parent::isValid($data);
        if ( ! $data['mail'] && ! $data['telephone'] && ! $data['postcode'] ){
            $this->addError('Please supply one of email, telephone or postcode');
            $valid = false;
        }
        return $valid;
    }

    //...

}
```

One small function, ties in with the form, easy to understand, unlikely to fail, unlikely to be a source of difficult bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
$foo->setRequired();
```

method from the two that you don't want to set as required....

```
$telephone->setLabel('Telephone:')
          ->setAttrib('size', 50)
          ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(10, 10))
          ->setRequired(true);
```

becomes

```
$telephone->setLabel('Telephone:')
          ->setAttrib('size', 50)
          ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(10, 10));
```

Comment: I think you don't understand my question, or I did formulate my question wrong.. I have 3 values, and only one of the 3 values should be required.. so if I full in value 1, for example email, and leave the other ones empty.. it should be accepted. If I fill in value 3 and leave the other ones empty, it should be accepted..

Comment: Ok so what you meant was *one of three of thme required* not just *one of them required*. Those two things are not the same.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. One of three required, other ones empty, sorry for asking it in the wrong way

Comment: No Problem - I should have known what you were asking I just thought you had a homework question or something....

Comment: It kind of is, it's a 6 months project